# How to use CombineFn with getKey

Tags: java, apache-beam

I have the following code:

```
PCollection<KV<String, Cell>> first = ...;

PCollection<String> lines = first
  .apply("Build lines", Combine.<String, Cell, String>perKey(new MergeCellsFn()))
;
```

`Cell` looks like:

```
public class Cell {
   public final int index;
   public final String value; 

   public Cell(int i, String value) {
      index = i;
      this.value = value;
   }
}
```

And the `MergeCellsFn`:

```
public class MergeCellsFn extends Combine.CombineFn<Cell, MergeCellsFn.Merger, String>
```

---

Now when I try to compile it fails on the above `apply` with:

```
incompatible types: inference variable OutputT has incompatible bounds
     equality constraints: org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection<org.apache.beam.sdk.values.KV<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>>
     lower bounds: org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection<java.lang.String>,org.apache.beam.sdk.values.POutput
```

All I could find online is that somewhere some lambda might do something implicitly. But from the error message I have no idea what and how to fix this let alone what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Changing to `PCollection<KV<String, String>> lines =`  makes this compile.